# Write relative xpath that selects all values present in list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using website https://www.techlistic.com/p/demo-selenium-practice.html
wherein i am using Demo table 2 for the reference
I am trying to write an xpath for a Web table wherein I need to get the list of all details in structure column below in the below list format

Burj Khalifa

Clock Tower Hotel

Taipei 101

Financial Center

I have written an relative xpath = //th[normalize-space()='Burj Khalifa'] but it only selects the first value. I require an relative xpath wherein it selects all the above values present in the list so that I can run a for loop
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below xpath expression will select all of your above mentioned/required data:

```
 //*[@class="tsc_table_s13"]/tbody/tr/th[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

select table with class "tsc_table_s13" and find the required data
`//table[@class="tsc_table_s13"]/tbody/tr/th`

if you want to get all the data in the table then use
`//table[@class="tsc_table_s13"]/tbody/tr` to loop over every row and use relative paths to get the required data like `.//th/text()` and so on